# Spring Framework Rest API's - Complex Validations in API

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring framework and is in process of learning it. While learning, I have some questions in my mind which I am trying to understand.

Any book or Online Tutorial when I am going through for building REST API's talk about doing CRUD operations on the database only. I have worked in Oracle SOA and we used to design lot of SOAP services which used to have the capability to do complex business validations (in database stored procedures being called from services). I am trying to relate the similar thing in REST API's in spring framework.

How does rest API developed in spring framework support the complex business validations which are dependent on data stored in relational database.

PS-> I am new to these JAVA frameworks but I do have background in JAVA.
Please help me understand.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. It seems you are wondering if business logic is implemented any differently is a REST API as opposed to a SOAP service. Business logic is business logic. It should be abstracted into services (or "Beans" in Spring lingo). You can reuse those services whether you are implementing a REST Controller or a SOAP service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am interested in knowing how and where to put any complex business validation logic in REST API's in spring framework.